# Setting Button text with an array item

Tags: java, android, arrays, button

I'm trying to set the text of a button from an array using a AlertDialog. I can bring up the array within the AlertDialog with no problem but how do I set the text to the item chosen? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Here's my array

```
<string-array name="Months">
    <item>January</item>
    <item>February</item> <item>March</item> <item>April</item>
    <item>May</item> <item>June</item> <item>July</item>
    <item>August</item> <item>September</item> <item>October</item>
    <item>November</item> <item>December</item>
</string-array>
```

And here is where I want to set the text

```
    button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Select a month");
            builder.setItems(R.array.Months, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                button.settext(""); // how do i set the text of the chosen item
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend doing it like this:

```
String[] months = { "January", "February", "March", ... "December" };

button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Select a month");
        builder.setItems(months, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                button.setText(months[which]);
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

try this: `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Months)[which];`